# SQL How to update previous and next row value without using lead and lag?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to flag some rows based on a value in a a column, but I also need to put same flag for previous and next row as well based on the current row value.

so below is my table

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  time INTEGER,
  event varchar NOT NULL
  );
-- insert some values
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, '1', 'r');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2, '2', 'r');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (3, '3', 's');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (4, '4', 'r');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (5, '5', 'r');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (6, '6', 'r');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (7, '7', 's');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (8, '8', 'r');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (9, '9', 'r');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (10, '10', 's');
```

I want to add a column `flag` that contains `0` for `event='s'` and also for it's previous and next row as well. but cannot use `lead` or `lag` or temp table due to system constraints.

so my final output looks like this

```
+-----------+--------+------+
| timestamp | events | flag |
+-----------+--------+------+
|         1 | r      |    1 |
|         2 | r      |    0 |
|         3 | s      |    0 |
|         4 | r      |    0 |
|         5 | r      |    1 |
|         6 | r      |    1 |
|         7 | r      |    0 |
|         8 | s      |    0 |
|         9 | r      |    0 |
|        10 | r      |    0 |
|        11 | s      |    0 |
+-----------+--------+------+
```

what I have tried so far is following

```
SELECT a.time, a.event, 0 as flag
FROM table1 AS a
JOIN table1 AS b
ON b.event = 's' AND abs(a.id - b.id) <= 1
```

I get all the rows which I need to flag as `0` but missing out on `1`

TimeStamp is ordered time but for ease of solving converted it to integer.

Comment: Your current solution **requires** no gaps in the values of id. Is that realistic?

Comment: @SMor, I am looking at it right now, so it's pretty much realistic

Comment: @AaronBertrand, mentioning `system resource contraint` should have been enough, btw I am using `SQL Sever 2008`

Comment: Sorry, no, `system resource constraint` is not specific enough for me to know `I am choosing to use 15-year old software that is completely out of support`.

Comment: ...especially when you mention that in the same sentence as "can't use temp table" - I didn't know temp tables didn't exist in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I suppose we should be asking why haven't you upgrading, and why won't you? 2008 has been *completely* unsupported for over 3 years now.

Comment: Seems there are multiple typos in the desired output. For row 6, the next row (7) has event "s" so it should have flag = 0, correct? And it seems you added a typo for row 7 since the table contains "s" for this row and not "r". And row 8 has similar problem.

Comment: Your expected output contains data different than the INSERT statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
With CTE As
(
  Select id, time, event,
  Case
      When event='r' then -10 else id
  End as f
  From table1
)
Select id, time, event,
Case 
    when id in 
    (select f from cte where f<>-10
    union
    select f+1 from cte where f<>-10
    union
    select f-1 from cte where f<>-10) then 0 else 1
End As flag
From CTE
```

Where the `-10` in `When event='r' then -10 else id` is any integer value not existed in the `id` column even if it has been added by 1.

See a demo from [***db<>fiddle***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=757687132542288ad3b3df511843f312).

***Update*** to cover the gaps in the `id` column:

```
With CTE As
(
Select M.id, M.time, M.event,
Case
    When M.event='r' then -10 else id
End as f,
Case 
    when M.event='s' then 
    (select top 1 T.id from table1 T where T.id > M.id order by T.id)
    else -10
End As Lead_val,
Case 
    when M.event='s' then 
    (select top 1 T.id  from table1 T where T.id < M.id order by T.id desc)
    else -10
End As Lag_val
From table1 M
)
Select T.id, T.time, T.event,
Case 
    when T.id in (
                   select f from cte
                   union
                   select Lead_val from cte
                   union
                   select Lag_val from cte
                  )
   then 0 else 1 
End as flag
From table1 T
```

See a demo from ***[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=403eec66c96d1b72b5e5a10f9bfaa986)***.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative. To address the possibility of gaps, I use row_number to generate a gap-less sequence and then use a self-join to avoid LEAD and LAG.

```
with cte as (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by time) as rno from table1
)
select main.*, 
    case when main.event = 's' then 0 
    when main.event <> 's' and after.event = 's' then 0 
    when main.event <> 's' and prior.event = 's' then 0 
    else 1 end as [flag], 
    prior.rno as [r-1], prior.id as [prior id], prior.event as [prior event],
    after.rno as [r+1], after.id as [after id], after.event as [after event]
from cte as main 
left join cte as prior on main.rno = prior.rno + 1
left join cte as after on main.rno = after.rno - 1
order by main.rno;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fd66b63fbb0b7af889cb0877df71e65d) to demonstrate - containing some extra rows with gaps to illustrate. It is not clear what logic is most appropriate for choosing the prior/next rows so I used the "time" column.